# "three cities that might, among them, contain no hospital"

Tags: between-among

Please take a look at the following sentence from an LSAT:

> if one of the cities contains exactly two hospitals and exactly one
> university, then which one of the following lists three cities that
> might, among them, contain no hospital?

After checking some explanations of this sentence, they all mention that the sentence actually asks to identify three cities that none of which contain a hospital.

I thought that "among" means "one or some of a group", so this sentence should be read as asking to identify three cities that some of which could have contained no hospitals.

I would really appreciate your help.
Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a group of cities has no hospital *among them*, it means there are no hospitals in any of the cities in the group. In other words, each city in the group has zero hospitals.

"Among" here means something like "taken together as a whole." The sum of the hospitals in the cities of the group is zero.